# how do i add the image based on index of the grid view android?

Tags: android

In my application i want to add the image in grid based on index. For example if I Don't want to add the image in [0,0] [ROW,COL] index. After that i want to add the image in [0,1] index. I searched for it, but i didn't get any idea. Please help me.

row and col details from json:

```
 "Layout": {
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "MaxRows": 14,
        "MaxColumns": 5,
        "SeatDetails": [
            {
                "ExtensionData": {},
                "Row": 0,
                "Col": 2,

            },
            {
                "ExtensionData": {},
                "Row": 1,
                "Col": 0,

            }
```

Comment: what you exjectly want clarify

Comment: From json every time i get row and col. based on the row and col i need  to put the particular image in grid. For example from json no need put a image in [0,0] and [0,1] index. i need to put a image in [0,2] index. (this data is always dynamic)

Comment: is json length is fixed everytime?

Comment: no because the maxrows and maxcol are also dynamic,,,based on the maxrow and maxcol also gridview index will increase.

Comment: So its better to use GridLayout and set row and column dynamically.

Comment: how i create dynamic grideview?

Answer (score 0):

Create one arraylist like this : `ArrayList<ArrayList<Model>>`,

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Model>>` contains Particular Row's data.

`ArrayList<Model>` contains row wise column's data.

`Model` contains the details of particular image like its name, path, etc.

If you do not want to put any image on [0][0] position, you can also achieve this by creating above ArrayList.

Comment: sorry. i didn't get u

Comment: Based on your JSON data which contains maxrows, maxcol jsonArray, create an ArrayList as i have mentioned above. Now, add your image data in that arraylist one by one from JSON and there you go! Your arraylist is ready for GridView.